# How to call unmanaged function which throws java.io.Exception in shared library from dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, java-native-interface

I have internal library that communicates with a special hardware. It is designed to call from java environment and uses JNI to export/extern functions. I am able call this kind of functions but an exception(java.io.Exception) thrown one of these functions and it is not catchable from dotnet core.

Created samples for describing the situation.

Hello.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Hello {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }
    private native void test1();
    private native void test2() throws IOException;
}
```

Hello.h ( generated by javac -h . Hello.java )

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Hello */

#ifndef _Included_Hello
#define _Included_Hello
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Hello
 * Method:    test1
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_test1
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     Hello
 * Method:    test2
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_test2
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Hello.cpp ( implementation sample )

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "iostream"

#ifndef _Included_Hello
#define _Included_Hello
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Hello
 * Method:    test1
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_test1
  (JNIEnv *, jobject) 
{
  std::cout << "Hello from C++ !!" << std::endl;
}

/*
 * Class:     Hello
 * Method:    test2
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_test2
  (JNIEnv* env, jobject) {
  jclass Exception = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
  env->ThrowNew(Exception, "something went wrong"); // Error Message  
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Craeted a new library called native (like libnative.so) using this samples. test1 function is working properly but test2 is not. Here is my pure native invocation.

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
namespace sample
{
    class MainClass
    {
        [DllImport("libnative.dylib")]
        public static extern void Java_Hello_test1();

        [DllImport("libnative.dylib", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern void Java_Hello_test2();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Java_Hello_test1();

            // crash with code 139 (segmentation fault)
            Java_Hello_test2();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using dotnet core 5.0 on linux and I wonder what is a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You want JVM features to work within .NET? That's simply not possible.

If you are looking for a proper solution, it would be one of:

- Port the Java application to .NET (or the other way around) to make sure there's only one VM running your code
- Use an implementation of .NET on top of Java so JNI will still work and the implementation will take care of translating the exceptions. Maybe IKVM.NET?
- Run the Java program and the .NET program as separate processes and use IPC to communicate between them.

Comment: Source code of the library is not available

Answer (score 1):

`JNIEnv*` object is C programming interface for the whole Java runtime. It contains methods to load classes, call methods of objects, and so on, [here’s some documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Realistically, you can’t implement that interface yourself, way too much work. It would mean implementing major parts of JRE.

A proper solution is integrating JVM. See that library http://jni4net.com/ I don’t have any experience, but at the first sight it’s good enough and might do what you need.